# Swift async/await, multiple listeners

Tags: swift, async-await

I want to implement something like multicast delegation using an async/await call, so if more than one client calls the same `async` method, when the value returns all clients receive it.

For instance, with pure callbacks could be something like this (simplified):

```swift
struct DataSource {
    typealias Listener = (Value) -> Void
    private var listeners: [Listener] = []

    func fetchData(_ callback: Listener) {
        listeners.append(callback)

        let value = ... // Get data from some async service

        listeners.forEach { $0(value) }
    }
}
```

But with async/await I am kind of lost, if I have this:

```swift
struct DataSource {
    func fetchData() async -> Value {
        let value = ... // Get data from some async service
        return value
    }
}
```

How can I get the returned value in N different places? Not an expert in new concurrency system so maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Make your Listener a Continuation instead of a closure

Comment: Use combine for these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hold onto the `Task` instead of the value, then you can do what you want like:

```
let task = Task { try await fetchData() } //  hold on to the task

let listener1 = await task.result
let listener2 = await task.result
```

Note that this will **NOT** call the task twice and just waits for the result.

Comment: It works! Thanks, super clear and easy.